# Make all elements of array equal by adding or subtracting

Tags: c++

Given an array of size n. Each element denotes the work assigned to some student. Taking some amount of work from a student and assigning it some other student will increase itny a factor of k.

Now we have to redistribute the work such that each student will do equal work. Determine minimum possible work value. And round it off to two decimal places.

A={2,8}
K= 1.5
You can take 2.4 from 8 and give it to 2.
A={ 2+2.4*1.5 , 8-2.4}
Answer is 5.60.

How can we approach to this question.
For n=2, I am able to do this simply ny solving equations. But for n>2, how can we approach to this.
I tried binary search. But I am getting Time limit Exceeded.

```
  
sort(a.begin(),a.end());
double low=a[0];
double high= a[n-1];
double res=INT_MAX;
double mid;
int i,j;
while(low<=high){
    mid=(low+high)/(2.0);
    i=0, j=n-1;
    while(i<=j){
        
        if((a[i]+k*a[j])==(k+1)*mid){
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else if((a[i]+k*a[j])<(k+1)*mid){
            high=mid;
            break;
        }
        else{
            low=mid;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(i>j){
        res=mid;
        high=mid;
    }
    
}
return res;
```

Please give me suggestions how I can overcome with Time limit exceeded.

Comment: Sorry if I am being inappropriate, but I cannot help it: we solve the problem by asking it in a question on StackOverflow, then the students do not have to do any work.

Comment: A binary search seems interesting effectively. The fact that the result is not an integer is not really a problem, as you only have to provide an approximate result. You should detail your approach in this direction.

Comment: No how this site works, show your code and what problem you are having with it.

Comment: I would try this approach: sort the students by the amount of initial work. If you assume that M students will receive more work, you can explicitly calculate the resulting amount of work, X_M, for each student. If this is larger than or equal to the initial work of the first M students and less than or equal to the initial work of the remaining students, then X_M is a solution. Otherwise, M is wrong and you need to try for another value of M. Thus a solution can be found by starting with M=1 and increment M until a valid solution is found.

Comment: @Damien  Can you look at my code now? What can be done to overcome time limit exceeded?

Comment: @Quimby Can you look at my code now? What can be done to overcome time limit exceeded?

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm has a O(n) complexity for each new value. The efficiency issue comes from it. Another approach consits as analysing the problem as a partition problem.

The principle is the following: if we split the array in two parts, the values that will be cecreaed and the value that will be decreased, then you calculate the new value. If this value is higher than all low values and lower than all high values, then it is done. If not, we have to modify the splitting in the array.

Two pre-processings allow to accelerate the implementation:

1. Sort the array. Complexity O(n logn)
2. For each index `i`, calculate the sum up to this index. Complexity O(n)

The last loop has a complexity O(n), as the index of the splitting value will alwas increase or decrease.

Total complexity: O(n logn).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename T>
void print (const std::vector<T>& v, const std::string& s = "") {
    std::cout << s;
    for (auto& x: v) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    //std::cout << std::endl
}

template<typename T>
double min_work (std::vector<T>& work, double penalty) {
    int n = work.size();
    if (n == 0) return 0.0;
    if (n == 1) return work[0];
    std::sort (work.begin(), work.end(), [&](T& i, T& j){return i > j;});
    std::vector<T> sum(n);
    sum[0] = work[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        sum[i] = sum[i-1] + work[i];
    }
    double minW = 0.0;
    int split = n/2 - 1;
    double eps = 1.0e-6;        /// to handle rounding
    while (true) {
        if (split == -1 || split == (n-1)) {
            return -1.0;
        }
        T sum_left = sum[split];
        T sum_right = sum[n-1] - sum_left;
        int rank = split + 1;
        minW = (double)(sum_right + penalty*sum_left) / (n - rank + penalty*rank);

        if (minW > (work[split] + eps)) {
            split--;
            continue;
        }
        if (minW < (work[split+1] - eps)) {
            split++;
            continue;
        }
        return minW;
    }
    return minW;
}

int main() {
    double penalty = 1.5;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> input = {{2, 8}, {1, 1, 5}, {8, 8, 0}};
    
    for (std::vector<int>& v: input) {
        print (v, "array : ");
        std::cout << std::endl;
        double ans = min_work (v, penalty);
        std::cout << "min work = " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << ans << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you finally posted a code, when I was trying to implementt his one. I will have a look at your code.

Comment: I see now that this paproach is the same as the one suggested by @nielsen in a comment.

Comment: Your implementation seems correct, Damien. @meenu, I am sorry to say that your revised code still looks fundamentally wrong. Speaking as a former teacher I hope you will study this answer carefully and learn from it. You have some way to go.