# Make all elements of the array equal under given conditions

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

Given an array of size n. Each element denotes the work assigned to some student. Taking some amount of work from a student and assigning it some other student will increase it by a factor of k.

Now we have to redistribute the work such that each student will do equal work. Determine minimum possible work value. And round it off to two decimal places.

A={2,8} K= 1.5 You can take 2.4 from 8 and give it to 2. A={ 2+2.4*1.5 , 8-2.4} Answer is 5.60.

How can we approach to this question. For n=2, I am able to do this simply by solving equations. But for n>2, how can we approach to this. I tried binary search. But I am getting Time limit Exceeded.

```
 
sort(a.begin(),a.end());
double low=a[0];
double high= a[n-1];
double res=INT_MAX;
double mid;
int i,j;
while(low<=high){
    mid=(low+high)/(2.0);
    i=0, j=n-1;
    while(i<=j){
        
        if((a[i]+k*a[j])==(k+1)*mid){
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else if((a[i]+k*a[j])<(k+1)*mid){
            high=mid;
            break;
        }
        else{
            low=mid;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(i>j){
        res=mid;
        high=mid;
    }
    
}
return res;
```

Please give me suggestions how I can overcome with Time limit exceeded.

Comment: are you sure by using floating point,  you're not running into infinite loop.

Comment: What did your tests report? And what did the debugger say?

Comment: @pawan but how can we do it without using double? the answer can be double or can be int

Comment: You must use Binary Search on real numbers, it has a finite number of iterations, so you could get pretty good precision with it, take a look her https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/63085   and here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-for-rational-numbers-without-using-floating-point-arithmetic/

Comment: It isn't quite clear what exactly you are searching, but `low<=high` will *always* be true. Maybe you wat to change it to `low<high`.

Comment: Why did you post the same question at one hour interval ?? -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/66622802/10553341

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly you have an array of doubles and you want to make all elements the same but, the condition is when you subtract you subtract normal but when you add you add multiplied by 1.5, it's basically calculating the average with a condition, so you want make an average and see if its close enough or not so, I made new variable difference that see if the average that we used is bigger or less than the real one, note that difference not give any real value just positive or negative

```
sort(a.begin(), a.end());
double low = a[0];
double high = a[n - 1];
double average, difference= 0;
average = (low + high) / 2;
do
{
    if (difference > 0)
    {
        low = average;
        average = average + high / 2;
    }
    else if (difference<0)
    {
        high = average;
        average = average + low / 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0, difference = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (a[i] < average)
            difference = difference + (a[i]-average) * 1.5;
        else
            difference = difference + a[i] - average;
} while (difference > 0.01 || difference < -0.01);
```

The while will done when difference is under 0.01 that's mean average is closer than 0.01 (you can say its 0.01/n almost).

I hope I answered your question, it's my first time to answer question here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with some math.

If you graph the values, and you found the target value `X`, then you would have valleys below `X` and mountains above `X`.  The volume of the mountains above `X`, times k, must equal the volume of the valleys.

If you sort the elements, then calculating the net mountain-valley volumes is a linear process.  Starting at a_0, all there is is mountain; this is a function of the sum of the a_is and k.

Going from a_i to a_{i+1} makes the a_0 to a_i valleys deeper by a_{i+1}-a_i, and makes the a_{i+1} to a_{last} mountains shallower by the same amount.

In that region the valley/mountain transformation is linear, if it is within that region you can do linear math to find the zero.

Walk from least to greatest, and find the point where the valleys match the mountains.